# WebView in java not showing map (google maps and leaflet)

Tags: google-maps, javafx, webview, maps, openstreetmap

**I'm trying to add a webview and webengine into java.**

*When I try it with openstreetmap, it is not problem.*

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/openlayers/OpenStreetMap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var map;
var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");

function start() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(4.7860003, 51.5891643)
        .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
        );

    var zoom = 12;
    map.addLayer(markers);
    map.setCenter(lonlat, zoom);
}

function addPin(lon, lat) {
    var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat)
        .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
        );

    theMarker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat);
    markers.addMarker(theMarker);
    map.addLayer(markers);
    var zoom = 16; // Adjust the zoom level as desired    
    map.setCenter(lonlat, zoom);
}

function removePins() {
    markers.clearMarkers();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="start()">
  <div id="mapdiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

But, I wanted to add routing and that's not possible. So, I tried it with leaflet, but the map is acting weird and items are overlapping.

So I tried using google maps and in javascript it is working with no problem. But when I try it in java I see nothing. I think it is a problem with javascript is too advanced.

*Google maps javascript*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Maps Integration</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        var markers = [];
        function start() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapdiv"), {
                center: {lat: 51.5891643, lng: 4.7860003},
                zoom: 12
            });
        }
        function addPin(lon, lat) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: lat, lng: lon},
                map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        }
        function removePins() {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
            markers = [];
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
    <div id="mapdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 96vh;"></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="addPin(4.5277088, 51.8969213)">Add Pin</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="removePins()">Remove Pins</button>
    <p id="adresstext">halo text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I show my google maps or leaflet as it looks in a normal browser in `WebView`, and have routing option.

I also tried adding: chromiumembedded-java-cef inside my JavaFX Maven but it is too difficult and no easy instruction.

The way I load it in my JavaFX:

```
try {
    URL url = new File("src/main/resources/mapOplaadpaal.html").toURI().toURL();
    engine.load(url.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I tried leaflet google maps and also mapping leaflet on top of openstreetmaps but still not working.

Comment: I tried to rescue your post by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77750713/revisions).  See the linked edit history to see the difference.  Please try to format code (any IDE can help you with that) and paste it correctly (there are instructions on how to add code in StackOverflow), as well as fix spelling and grammar errors (grammarly can do that for you).